# redis zset zrevrangebyscore result with score low to high

Tags: redis, zset

The redis zset 'zrevrangebyscore' command will get the result with score from high to low.
Now I want to get the result with score from low to high directly rather than use java code to resort the searched result one more time.

Is it possible?

Comment: try `zrangebyscore`

Comment: the result is from low to high score.